# Hypergeometric distribution with a priori probabilities of the balls

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

If we have a urn with $N$ balls of two colours ($D$ red and $N-D$ black balls respectively), then probability of having $k$ red out of $n$ balls drawn *at once without replacement* follows the *Hypergeometric distribution*:

$Pr(X = k) = \dfrac{\binom{D}{k} \binom{N - D}{n-k}}{\binom{N}{n}}$

Now assume we have some *a priori* distribution of the balls: $p_i$ – probability of drawing ball $i$, $i \in \{1, \ldots, N \}$. (Note that it's unrelated to colours.)

Let's make an experiment with drawing balls again. 
As a result of the experiment we have the following:

$P_n = \{p_{i_1}, \ldots, p_{i_n}\}$ – probabilities of $n$ drawn balls

$P_k = \{p_{j_1}, \ldots, p_{j_k}\}$ – probabilities of $k$ red drawn balls, $P_k \subset P_n $

What the probability of having *this result*, i.e. having $k$ balls out of $n$ drawn balls which probabilities turned out to be *exactly* $P_k$ and $P_n$ respectively?

**Example**.

Say we have a urn with $N = 6$ balls ($D = 3$ are red) with probabilities as follows:

$$
\underbrace{\stackrel{\frac{1}{21}}{A} \quad \stackrel{\frac{2}{21}}{B} \quad \stackrel{\frac{3}{21}}{C}}_\text{red} \quad \underbrace{\stackrel{\frac{4}{21}}{D} \quad \stackrel{\frac{5}{21}}{E} \quad \stackrel{\frac{6}{21}}{F}}_\text{black}
$$

Let $n = 3, k = 2$. Let's consider two cases.

1. $P_k = \{\frac{1}{21}, \frac{2}{21}\}, P_n = \{\frac{4}{21}\}$
2. $P_k = \{\frac{2}{21}, \frac{3}{21}\}, P_n = \{\frac{4}{21}\}$

In both cases we have the same number of drawn balls and the same number of red balls out of them. Moreover, we have the same probability of the black drawn set of balls. But intuitively it's clear that the probability of having first case as a result is *less probable* (or more significant in terms of statistical hypothesis testing).

Hypergeometric distribution as it is can't distinguish these two cases, since it assumes equal probability of each ball ($\frac{1}{N}$).

Do you have any idea of how to take the probability into account in hypergeometric distribution? Or maybe you know the name of distribution that fits the problem?

Appreciate any thoughts about the solution.

**UPD**

It's may be enough just to *estimate* the probability. This admission stems from the purpose of this research – *ranking* experiment results by *statistical significance*.

Comment: Forget the hypergeometric distribution. Your example is actually $2^6=64$ elementary outcomes (each ball either gets drawn or not); you may easily count them all. If we put it this way: $$\underbrace{\stackrel{0.05}A\quad\stackrel{0.05}B\quad\stackrel{0.4}C}_{red} \quad \underbrace{\stackrel{0.05}D\quad\stackrel{0.05}E\quad\stackrel{0.4}F}_\text{blue or whatever}$$
then what are the outcomes leading to case 1? and what about case 2?

Comment: I ain't sure I've gotten your question. 
As I understood so far, you just fix two experiments where number of drawn balls ($n$) and drawn red balls ($k$) are equal, except for _probabilities_ of the red drawn balls. Then you relate to the first case _less probable_ (more significant) result (in terms of red drawn balls) and to second – _more probable_.

Please correct me if I got you wrong.

Comment: I don't quite get you either, so we are even. Well, here is your urn with 6 balls, 3 of them red, each ball with its certain predefined probability (is that right?) of getting drawn. I just signed the balls with letters A, B, C, D, E, F, so that we could tell one from the other. Now what exactly is the case 1 you were talking about?

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. We can put them as follows. _Case 1_: {A, B} – red, {F} – black. _Case 2_: {A, C} – red, {D} – black.

Comment: Fine. I don't see any sense in listing them separately, since we know anyway which is red and which is not. So the elementary outcome {A,B,F} belongs to case 1. Likewise, {A,C,D} belongs to case 2; but is it alone in this respect? What about {A,C,E}?

Comment: {A, C, E} is the same as {A, C, D} for us in terms of significance.

Comment: That's right: these outcomes belong to case 2. (Aren't there more of them, BTW?) This means their probabilities add together. And that's why your first case (which corresponds to just one elementary outcome) is less probable than the second.

Comment: These cases are just the way to make out between _two_ outcomes: I wanted to show the (intuitive) difference in getting certain number of _red_ balls out of $n$. So it doesn't make sense to consider the probability of getting an outcome with specific subset of probabilities (of red balls) by counting the total number of outcomes with this subset. E.g. if we put $$\{\frac{1}{21}, \frac{2}{21}, \ldots, \frac{6}{21} \}$$ for balls {A, B, ..., F} respectively,then each outcome is unique in terms of set of probabilities, but case 1 is still more significant than case 2. Let me clarify the problem.

Comment: Well, the general approach is pretty much the same: locate the elementary outcomes belonging to each case, find their individual probabilities (they are no longer equal, but that's no problem), and sum them up to find the probability of each case.

Comment: If we draw $n$ balls out of $N$ having some probabilities on balls, then probability of certain set of $n$ drawn balls is:
$$\frac{\prod_{i \in \text{drawn}} p_i \times \prod_{i \notin \text{drawn}} (1 - p_i)}{\sum_{\text{all subsets S of size n from N}} \prod_{i \in S} p_i \times \prod_{i \notin S} (1 - p_i)}$$

So, it's may be extremely hard to compute. That's why I'm interesting in _approximation_ as well.

Comment: That's right, it looks like a problem of exponential complexity and I don't believe it will simplify nicely. Never heard of an approximation either, but I'm not an expert. Let's wait for someone more knowledgeable.